# Error CS0234 after changing the .NET framework version of my Xamarin GTK# app

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, gtk#

Full error message:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'GTK' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This occurs in Program.cs on this line:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.GTK;
```

The reason I had to change the .NET framework version is because I was trying to run the app on Linux, and Mono for Linux doesn't seem to support .NET Framework v4.7.2, so I changed it to 4.6.1 (the minimum required for Xamarin).

The weird thing is, if I open the file in question, Visual Studio says there are no errors, but the error still pops up in the output window when I actually try to build the project...

edit: there are some warnings above the error in the output window, here is the first one:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3274: The primary reference "Xamarin.Forms.Platform.GTK, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1".

This looks like I need to update my nuget packages, so I reinstalled the two Xamarin packages (Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Forms.Platform.GTK), and... same warning! Why can't nuget get the version of the package that is compatible with the version of .NET that I'm using?

edit: the reason I tried to change the .NET framework version is because I get this error running the Xamarin app on Linux:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
>   File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
>   File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Comment: check the output window there must be some other error also appearing there

Comment: delete and re-install your GTK packages, delete your bin/obj folders, restart VS, rebuild

Comment: Deleting bin and job and restarting Visual Studio didn't help. I see some warnings above the error that I'll past into my OP.

Comment: [Xamarin.Forms.Platform.GTK is built to target .Net 4.7](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.GTK/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.GTK.csproj) despite [its nuspec claiming otherwise](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/.nuspec/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.GTK.nuspec).

Comment: However, why do you claim mono does not support .Net 4.7? It says it's compatible on its [compatibility page](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/).

Comment: I got a `FileNotFoundException` for some system DLL or other when I try to run my app using .NET 4.7.2. Was going to post that error here instead of the error I'm getting now, but I Googled it and people were saying that Mono doesn't support .NET 4.7.2. Of course, that could be old information... let me go find that error and share it here!

Comment: update your mono version, it should support 4.7.2

Comment: I expect Xamarin forms is leveraging the GTK libraries underneath, I wonder if installing the latest GTK# would do the trick?